# Return different Fragment Types

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, android-listfragment

I have the following method which gives back different Fragments:

```
@Override
    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        SherlockFragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new MyFragment2();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new MyListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

How can I return 2 times a SherlockFragment and 1 time a SherlockListFragment?

Comment: Hi I have got a similar issue where based on a particular condition I have to return a different fragment. How can I go about that. Plese share your ideas on the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030296/populate-different-fragments-inside-viewpager-with-data can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it this way

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new MyFragment2();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new MyListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Hello I have a similar problem actualy I have got my fragments inside a viewpager but want to return a different fragment based on a particular condition.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18030296/1503130